# Handling many outgoing TCP connections

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04

I was testing a server on EC2 with "High" network performance to check the maximum outgoing connections I could use on it. Without changing any settings, by opening around ~1000 threads which each sends a TCP request, after 10 minutes or so, I get 'connection refused' error which I am sure its the problem with my side as I know the target server doesn't see any errors.

I followed the instructions on [this article](http://www.krenel.org/tcp-time_wait-and-ephemeral-ports-bad-friends/) which talks about `TIME_WAIT` and `Ephemeral ports` so I did these:

1. Increasing the number of ephemeral ports
2. Enabling tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse

By doing these two, I still get the errors but after a longer period like hours. In general, I wanna know how much an Ubuntu server with a specific hardware configuration can handle network traffic. How can I monitor the outgoing traffic so I can figure out what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Did u manage? I suck with same issue. Maximum 1000 outgoing connection from 1 host.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor outgoing traffic look at the following tools: tshark, tcpdump, ettercap.

Also look at these settings:

```
root@server ~ # sysctl -A | grep -i wait
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
```